Проблема внедрения HorizontalPager в MotionLayout
У меня есть такой код :
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            val list = listOf(R.raw.coffe_big, R.raw.coffe_big, R.raw.coffe_big)
            DrinkKitTestMainScreenTheme {
                RecipeDetail(list)
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMotionApi::class, ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun RecipeDetail(list: List<Int>) {
    val motionState = rememberMotionLayoutState()
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val motionScene = remember {
        context.resources
            .openRawResource(R.raw.motion_scene)
            .readBytes()
            .decodeToString()
    }

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        initialPageOffsetFraction = 0f
    ) {
        return@rememberPagerState list.size
    }

    val videoUri = rawResourceUri(context, list[0])

    val player = remember {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
            val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri)
            setMediaItem(mediaItem)
            repeatMode = ExoPlayer.REPEAT_MODE_ONE
            prepare()
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(motionState) {
        snapshotFlow { motionState.currentProgress }.collect { progress ->
            player.playWhenReady = true
        }
    }
    DisposableEffect(player) {
        onDispose {
            player.release()
        }
    }
    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = Modifier
            .layoutId("HorizontalPager")
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) { page ->
        MotionLayout(
            motionScene = MotionScene(content = motionScene),
            motionLayoutState = motionState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Transparent)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTapGestures(onTap = {})
                }
        ) {
            AndroidView(
                modifier = Modifier.layoutId("headerImage"),
                factory = {
                    PlayerView(it).apply {
                        this.player = player
                        useController = false
                        resizeMode =
                            AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL
                    }
                }
            )
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .background(
                        White,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 10.dp, topEnd = 10.dp)
                    )
                    .layoutId("contentBg")
            )
            Text(
                color = Color.White,
                text = "Fresh Strawberry Cake", fontSize = 22.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold, modifier = Modifier

                    .layoutId("title_price")
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(10.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = list[page].toString(), fontSize = 22.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold, modifier = Modifier
                    .layoutId("title")
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(10.dp)
            )

            Divider(
                Modifier
                    .layoutId("titleDivider")
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 34.dp)
            )

            Text(
                text = "by John Kanell", fontSize = 16.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                color = Gray, fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .layoutId("subTitle")
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(6.dp)
            )
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .layoutId("date")
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(6.dp),
                text = "September, 2022", fontSize = 16.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                color = Gray
            )
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .layoutId("actions")
                    .background(Color.DarkGray),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "texttttttt",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .layoutId("text")
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                    fontSize = 12.sp,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

В данный момент скрол-свайп в HorizontalPager просто не работает.
я также пропобовал поместить HorizontalPager внутрь MotionLayout, но тогда весь контент кроме Android View пропадают :
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            val list = listOf(R.raw.coffe_big, R.raw.coffe_big, R.raw.coffe_big)
            DrinkKitTestMainScreenTheme {
                RecipeDetail(list)
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMotionApi::class, ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun RecipeDetail(list: List<Int>) {
    val motionState = rememberMotionLayoutState()
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val motionScene = remember {
        context.resources
            .openRawResource(R.raw.motion_scene)
            .readBytes()
            .decodeToString()
    }

    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        initialPageOffsetFraction = 0f
    ) {
        return@rememberPagerState list.size
    }

    val videoUri = rawResourceUri(context, list[0])

    val player = remember {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
            val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri)
            setMediaItem(mediaItem)
            repeatMode = ExoPlayer.REPEAT_MODE_ONE
            prepare()
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(motionState) {
        snapshotFlow { motionState.currentProgress }.collect { progress ->
            player.playWhenReady = true
        }
    }
    DisposableEffect(player) {
        onDispose {
            player.release()
        }
    }

    MotionLayout(
        motionScene = MotionScene(content = motionScene),
        motionLayoutState = motionState,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Transparent)
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectTapGestures(onTap = {})
            }
    ) {
        HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .layoutId("HorizontalPager")
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) { page ->
            AndroidView(
                modifier = Modifier.layoutId("headerImage"),
                factory = {
                    PlayerView(it).apply {
                        this.player = player
                        useController = false
                        resizeMode =
                            AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL
                    }
                }
            )
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .background(
                        White,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 10.dp, topEnd = 10.dp)
                    )
                    .layoutId("contentBg")
            )
            Text(
                color = Color.White,
                text = "Fresh Strawberry Cake", fontSize = 22.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold, modifier = Modifier

                    .layoutId("title_price")
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(10.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = list[page].toString(), fontSize = 22.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold, modifier = Modifier
                    .layoutId("title")
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(10.dp)
            )

            Divider(
                Modifier
                    .layoutId("titleDivider")
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 34.dp)
            )

            Text(
                text = "by John Kanell", fontSize = 16.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                color = Gray, fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .layoutId("subTitle")
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(6.dp)
            )
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .layoutId("date")
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(6.dp),
                text = "September, 2022", fontSize = 16.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                color = Gray
            )
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .layoutId("actions")
                    .background(Color.DarkGray),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "texttttttt",
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .layoutId("text")
                        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                    fontSize = 12.sp,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

и также после этого при попытки начать анимацию выходит                                                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.constraintlayout.core.state.Transition$WidgetState.interpolate(int, int, float, androidx.constraintlayout.core.state.Transition)' on a null object reference
я также пытался в motion_scene внедрить HorizontalPager :
{
  "ConstraintSets": {
    "start": {
      "headerImage": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "spread",
        "top": [
          "parent",
          "top",
          0
        ],
        "bottom": [
          "parent",
          "bottom",
          0
        ],
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start",
          0
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end",
          0
        ],
        "translationY": 0,
        "alpha": 1
      },
      "HorizontalPager": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "wrap",
        "top": [
          "parent",
          "top",
          0
        ],
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start",
          0
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end",
          0
        ]
      },
      "title_price": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "wrap",
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start"
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end"
        ],
        "top": [
          "parent",
          "top",
          550
        ],
        "translationY": 0,
        "alpha": 1
      },
      "title": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "wrap",
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start"
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end"
        ],
        "top": [
          "parent",
          "top",
          650
        ]
      },
      "titleDivider": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "wrap",
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start"
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end"
        ],
        "top": [
          "title",
          "bottom"
        ]
      },
      "subTitle": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "wrap",
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start"
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end"
        ],
        "top": [
          "titleDivider",
          "bottom"
        ]
      },
      "subTitleDivider": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "wrap",
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start"
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end"
        ],
        "top": [
          "subTitle",
          "bottom"
        ]
      },
      "contentBg": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "spread",
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start",
          16
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end",
          16
        ],
        "top": [
          "parent",
          "top",
          650
        ],
        "bottom": [
          "parent",
          "bottom"
        ]
      },
      "date": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "wrap",
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start"
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end"
        ],
        "top": [
          "subTitleDivider",
          "bottom"
        ]
      },
      "actions": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": 50,
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start",
          16
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end",
          16
        ],
        "top": [
          "date",
          "bottom"
        ]
      },
      "text": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "spread",
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start",
          16
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end",
          16
        ],
        "top": [
          "actions",
          "bottom",
          16
        ],
        "bottom": [
          "parent",
          "bottom"
        ]
      }
    },
    "end": {
      "headerImage": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": 750,
        "top": [
          "parent",
          "top",
          0
        ],
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start",
          0
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end",
          0
        ],
        "translationY": -250,
        "alpha": 0.3
      },
      "HorizontalPager": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "wrap",
        "top": [
          "parent",
          "top",
          0
        ],
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start",
          0
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end",
          0
        ]
      },
      "contentBg": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "spread",
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start"
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end"
        ],
        "top": [
          "parent",
          "top"
        ],
        "bottom": [
          "parent",
          "bottom"
        ]
      },
      "title": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "wrap",
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start"
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end"
        ],
        "top": [
          "parent",
          "top",
          6
        ]
      },
      "title_price": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": 750,
        "top": [
          "parent",
          "top",
          0
        ],
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start",
          0
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end",
          0
        ],
        "translationY": -250,
        "alpha": 0.3
      },
      "titleDivider": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "wrap",
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start",
          34
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end",
          34
        ],
        "top": [
          "title",
          "bottom"
        ]
      },
      "subTitle": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "wrap",
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start"
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end"
        ],
        "top": [
          "titleDivider",
          "bottom"
        ]
      },
      "subTitleDivider": {
        "visibility": "gone",
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "wrap",
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start"
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end"
        ],
        "top": [
          "subTitle",
          "bottom"
        ]
      },
      "date": {
        "visibility": "gone",
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "wrap",
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start"
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end"
        ],
        "top": [
          "subTitleDivider",
          "bottom"
        ]
      },
      "actions": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": 70,
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start"
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end"
        ],
        "top": [
          "subTitle",
          "bottom"
        ]
      },
      "text": {
        "width": "spread",
        "height": "spread",
        "start": [
          "parent",
          "start"
        ],
        "end": [
          "parent",
          "end"
        ],
        "top": [
          "actions",
          "bottom",
          16
        ],
        "bottom": [
          "parent",
          "bottom"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Transitions": {
    "default": {
      "from": "start",
      "to": "end",
      "onSwipe": {
        "anchor": "contentBg",
        "direction": "up",
        "side": "top"
      }
    }
  }
} 

но что и с HorizontalPager, что и без HorizontalPager в motion_scene ничего не поменялось , также не видно элемнеты и выходит ошибка
